# Flatten a sequence of sequences into a single sequence (List<string> from List<Object> contains that List<string>)

Tags: c#, linq, .net-6.0

I'm trying to extract some Lists of strings into a single List.
First I have this class

```
public class Client
{
  public string Name { get; set; }

  public List<string> ApiScopes { get; set; }
}
```

Thus I'm getting my response as a `List<Client>`  and my intention is to take all Client's Scopes into a single List without Looping
I've tried this by LINQ:

```
 var x = clients.Select(c=> c.AllowedScopes.Select(x => x).ToList()).ToList();
```

this returns a `List<List<string>>`, and I just want to get all this into one Distinct list of strings.

Comment: `clients.SelectMany()`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It sounds like you want `SelectMany` (which flattens a sequence of sequences into a single sequence), with `Distinct` as well if you need a list with each scope only appearing once even if it's present for multiple clients:

```cs
var scopes = clients.SelectMany(c => c.ApiScopes).Distinct().ToList();
```

This assumes that `Client.ApiScopes` is never null. If it might be null, you need a little bit more work:

```cs
var scopes = clients
    .SelectMany(c => ((IEnumerable<string>) c.ApiScopes) ?? Enumerable.Empty<string>())
    .Distinct()
    .ToList();
```

Comment: It's working fine now, if we need a List<string> as a result, why did you make this cast (IEnumerable<string>)?

Comment: @esamaldinelzain: Because `SelectMany` only needs the function to return an `IEnumerable<string>`, and I wanted to use `Enumerable.Empty<string>()` instead of creating a new `List<string>` when the value is null.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [SelectMany](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.selectmany?view=net-6.0) to flatten results :

```
var scopes=clients.SelectMany(client=>client.ApiScopes)
                  .Distinct()
                  .ToList();
```

This is equivalent to :

```
var scopes= ( from client in clients
              from scope in client.ApiScopes
              select scope
            )
            .Distinct()
            .ToList();
```